# get original file name of resource in qrc file

Tags: qt, qfile, qresource

**Problem:**

How can I get the original file name from the [qrc resource file](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)?

**More Info:**

Using [fileName()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qresource.html#fileName) and [absoluteFilePath()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qresource.html#absoluteFilePath) methods, I implemented the following example:

```
qrc entry:

:/my/file           (somefile.txt)
```

Here, I expect to see (atleast):

```
somefile.txt
```

or

```
:/my/somefile.txt
```

**Implemented Code:**

```
QFile file(":/my/file");
QResource r(file.fileName)
qDebug() << r.fileName();
qDebug() << r.absoluteFilePath();
```

Output:

```
":/my/file"
":/my/file"
```

Do I misunderstand the doc page, or am I just doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do what you're asking with [QResource](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qresource.html#QResource):

> QResource is an object that represents a set of data (and possibly children) relating to a single resource entity.

So you can grab the resource file itself, like `file://path/to/your/file.qrc`, but not the contents of your files.

Why do you need the absolute file path? Can you provide some use case?

Comment: A use case would be to get the file extension. So, we know `:/my/file` is actually a `txt` file.